# Make Unity Text Area to act like a logger

Tags: unity, gui, text

I'm trying to create a text area in Unity using `UI.Text` that contains multi-line text which should act like a log view, i.e the text area `Vertical Overflow` is set to `Truncate` and a new line of text is added to the `text` property every now and then but instead of the text being eventually cut of at the bottom when the text area is full I want the text to 'scroll' up so that the newest added line is always the last displayed at the bottom of the text area, e.g.

```
  Line 1
  Line 2
+------------------------------------------+
| Line 3                                   |
| Line 4                                   |
| Line 5                                   |
| Line 6                                   |
| Line 7                                   |
| Line 8                                   |
+------------------------------------------+
```

... When Line 7 is logged Line 1 goes out of the text area at the top, when Line 8 is logged, Line 2 goes out, etc. Can this be done with UI.Text?

Comment: "Can this be done?" Yes.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, but not with UI.Text directly, or do you have a direct solution?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a scroll rect. But if you wanted to do it with JUST a text box, you could, but it would be a real pain.

Comment: @Draco18s Scrollrect and 'physical' scrolling is what I want to prevent. I now have another solution however: figure out the number of lines of the Text, create a string-only backbuffer with the size of the line count, then pop/unshift lines from the back buffer as needed and update the Text area whenever the buffer changes.

Comment: Yep, that's the convoluted alternative

Comment: @Draco18s not really convoluted. Actually quite clean and can generate a very performant scroll area, as long as pixel-wise scrolling isn't needed. It's exactly what I need.

Comment: Post your code and I'll upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but it came up for me in a Google search so I thought I'd post the solution I came up with. In short Use a string FIFO Queue the same size as the text box.

```
// outputText is the text box.
private Queue textQueue = new Queue();
public void SetOutputText(string outputmsg) {
    if (textQueue.Count > 4) {
        textQueue.Dequeue();
    }
    // you should strip out newlines and handle long lines before storing in the queue
    // that code is not shown here.
    textQueue.Enqueue(outputmsg);
    // rewrite the text each time by joining the FIFO queue elements with a \n newline.
    outputText.text = string.Join("\n", textQueue.ToArray());
}
```

This is not bulletproof. If your outputmsg is too long and wraps, or it contains new lines, it will not fit in outputText so you need to write additional code here to account for that. Also if you use larger fonts for part of the text or anything else that dynamically changes line spacing this won't work.